# declaring global array in Visual Basic Editor

Tags: arrays, vba

No other answer seems to work for me so I'm resorting to asking a question that everyone sees to be having trouble with. Simple stuff on any other language but VBA. I just want to initialize a global array of strings, and make use of it in my main sub.

Here's test1 where I just tried to return it from a public function:

```
Public Function effthis1() As String()
    ReDim effthis1(0 To 10)
    myStr = "a b c d e f g h i j k"
    strsplit = Split(myStr)

    j = LBound(effthis)
    For Each word In strsplit
        effthis1(j) = word
        j = j + 1
    Next

End Function

Sub test1()
    testStr = effthis1(4)
    MsgBox testStr
End Sub
```

Here's test2 where I tried with a sub that gets called within the main sub:

```
Public effthis2() As String

Sub declareMyArray()

effthis2(0) = "a"
effthis2(1) = "b"
effthis2(2) = "c"
effthis2(3) = "d"
effthis2(4) = "e"
effthis2(5) = "f"
effthis2(6) = "g"
effthis2(7) = "h"
effthis2(8) = "i"
effthis2(9) = "j"
effthis2(10) = "k"

End Sub

Sub test2()
    declareMyArray
    MsgBox effthis2(4)
End Sub
```

MSDN is not helping at all. Thanks in advance, George

Comment: if you want to use a variable in any sub or function you have to declare it at the top, before the first sub or function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 2nd example you must allocate the size of the array prior to assigning to it, so change it to:

```
ReDim effthis2(10)

effthis2(0) = "a"
effthis2(1) = "b"
...
```

(A public array must also be within a module)

Comment: Yields a compile error on the sub test2() line, stating the sub or function is not defined.

Comment: I copy/paste example 2 into a new module, add `ReDim effthis2(10)` as the first line of `declareMyArray` run `test2` and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

With your first example, You must declare the variable, then ther is no need to run a loop just get that string.

```
Public Function effthis1(j As Integer) As String
    Dim strsplit() As String
    myStr = "a b c d e f g h i j k"
    strsplit = Split(myStr)

    effthis1 = strsplit(j)

End Function

Sub test1()
    testStr = effthis1(4)
    MsgBox testStr
End Sub
```

Edit:

Per your comment then the teststr must be an array into which you load the entire array:

```
Public Function effthis1() As String()

    myStr = "a b c d e f g h i j k"
    effthis1 = Split(myStr)

End Function

Sub test1()

    teststr = effthis1
    MsgBox teststr(4)
End Sub
```

Comment: With my example code, I intend the msgbox to use the 4th index of the public array, not use it as an additional input argument. Although, your code is a handy workaround for that, that I'll record and use in the future. Thanks!